# Reuse user in multi-stage Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As you know, for security reasons, isn't good to use root user execept if you need it. I have this Dockerfile that I use with multi-stage steps

```
FROM golang:latest AS base

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Create User and working dir
RUN addgroup --gid 42000 app
RUN useradd --create-home --uid 42000 --gid app app
RUN chown -R app:app /usr/src/app
RUN chmod 755 /usr/src/app

# Compile stage based on Debian
FROM base AS builder

USER app

# Copy form computer to current WORKDIR container
COPY . .

# Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status
RUN set -xue && \
  make go-build-linux

# Final stage
FROM debian:latest

USER app

EXPOSE 14001

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y ca-certificates

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/server .

CMD ["./server"]
```

The problem is that I'm trying to reuse the user in all steps but seems to be that the user scope is by stage and I don't know how to reuse it.

Do you know how I can reuse a user in a multi-stage Dockerfile and try to avoid to use root user from Dockerfile?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the point in avoiding building as `root`? Why not only create the user in the final layer and [`COPY --chown=42000:42000 --from=builder ...`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)?

Comment: This I what I'm doing right now, but my concern is about root, if I can avoid to use it it's better. because, for security, for example. We are using some dependencies and try to avoid to install it as root it's better.

Comment: It's one thing to run the service as `root` user, it's another to build as the `root` user. If your scurity people are serious I'd expect that they lint your `Dockerfile` using i.e. `hadolint` which will error out if [the last user is root](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL3002). Some services can only be run as `root` user (i.e. `sshd`) in which case they'd probably [map the `root` user inside of the container to a non-privileged user on the host OS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR;

It is not possible to re-use the same user in multiple stages of the `docker` build without re-creating the user (same `UID` and `GID` at least) in each stage as each `FROM` is starting from a clean slate `FROM image` in which a user `UID=42000` and `GID=42000` is unlikely to already exist.

---

I am not aware of any recommendation against building as the `root` user inside a container. It is [recommended to run services as unprivileged users however certain containers processes must be run as the `root` user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) (i.e. `sshd`):

> The best way to prevent privilege-escalation attacks from within a container is to configure your container’s applications to run as unprivileged users. For containers whose processes must run as the `root` user within the container, you can re-map this user to a less-privileged user on the Docker host. The mapped user is assigned a range of UIDs which function within the namespace as normal UIDs from 0 to 65536, but have no privileges on the host machine itself.

***Tip***: The [Haskell Dockerfile Linter](https://hadolint.github.io/hadolint/) will complain if [the last user is root](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL3002) which you can configure as a [`git` `pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to catch things like that before committing teh codez.

Comment: So, will it be fine if we add the non root user to the final stage or should all the stages run under non-root user?

Comment: Just the final stage should be fine.